# jQuery AJAX running twice on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make two Ajax calls in one page using jQuery. The first Ajax runs successfully and produces results. Second Ajax is supposed to fire up on button click and show the result, but it runs twice every time I click on the button. And initially on the first time clicking on the button, I have to click twice before it produces a result. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
function showPicture() {
$("button").click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'displaySearch.php',
    data: {'getTile': $(this).val()},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(id);
      $("#" + id).replaceWith("<img src=" + data + " />");
    }
  });
});
```

}

Here's my button:

```
<button id=" . $count . " onclick=showPicture() value=" . htmlentities($result['Poster']) . ">Click Me!</button>
```

I have seen similar questions on Google but I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are running two `on clicks`

Comment: If I try to remove the function showPicture() or the jQuery's button on click function, it doesn't work.

Comment: you could remove the function, give the button a class, and then just use `$('.classOfButton').on('click', function(){WhatEverHere;});` and be sure, that it is in a `.ready`

Comment: by ready do you mean $( document ).ready() ? I'm sorry but I'm very new and very bad at JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 onClick handlers, somewhat:

1. `onClick`
2. `$("button").click()`

Remove one of the handlers.

### Example

```
function showPicture(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'displaySearch.php',
    data: {'getTile': $(this).val()},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(id);
      $("#" + id).replaceWith("<img src=" + data + " />");
    }
  });
}

<button id=" . $count . " onclick=showPicture(" . $count . ") value=" . htmlentities($result['Poster']) . ">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Hello. I have already tried that and it gives me an error:

TypeError: i.nodeName is undefined
 val
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:67502

showPicture
http://localhost/lab4/:12:31

onclick
http://localhost/lab4/:1:1

Comment: Oh nvm. I figured it out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your function 'showPicture' which you are calling from the html attribute below

```
 <button id=" . $count . " onclick=showPicture()
```

is calling your function as you would expect.

but the function showPicture() itself is then binding a onclick event

```
function showPicture() {

     $("button").click(function() {  <------- this
 ......
```

So it is being hit twice as you have the attribute onclick and the even binding onclick.
The event click is on all html buttons.

What you should do: Remove the binding in the function to all buttons

```
function showPicture(caller) {

   var id = $(caller).attr("id");
   var val = $(caller).val();

   console.log(id);
   console.log(val);

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'displaySearch.php',
      data: {'getTile': val },
      success: function(res) {

         --you are replacing the button with an image... or something like that
         $("#" + id).replaceWith("<img src=" + res+ " />");
      }
  });
}
```

html

```
<button id=".$count." onclick="showPicture(this)" value=".htmlentities($result['Poster']).">Click Me!</button>
```